# select from function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to exit the function when the first condition is met. but I get the error "relation" tab "does not exist". what could be the problem? For example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function test_func(id int)
 RETURNS TABLE(results_q int4,flag character varying)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
    act_res int:= null;
    reason              varchar(255)        := null; 

begin
 with tab as (
     select 4/id  as res 
     where id = 2
    )

    select res into act_res from tab;

    if (act_res is not null)
    then
    return query 
    select res,
    case when res = 2 then 'Y'::varchar  end as flag
    from tab
    ;
    else 
  return query  with tab2 as (
     select 4+id  as res 
     )  
     select res,
     'N'::varchar as flag
    from tab2;

end if;
end;
$function$
;
```

if I pass "2", I want to perform a select from tab and complete the function.
Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
with tab as (
     select 4/id  as res 
     where id = 2
    )
```

The id you pass into the function is not going to be used in the `where` clause.

You probably want something like:

```
IF id = 2 THEN
   with tab as (
        select 4/id  as res 
    )

    select res into act_res from tab;
END IF;
```

General tip, it is not good idea to name the parameters the same as SQL identifiers e.g. table, column names. plpgsql will complain in many instances. Use something like _id or id_val.